# What is the difference between `Allow: /` & `Disallow: ` in robots.txt?

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

What is the difference between the two `robots.txt` files below?

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

vs.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

---

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) it lists the later as an example under the `Examples` section.

However later it has code similar to the first code:

```
User-agent: bingbot
Allow : /
Crawl-delay: 10
```

Comment: `Disallow:` doesn't disallow anything, and `Allow: /` allows everything, so there's no difference.

Answer (score 3):

You should prefer to use the disallow syntax:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

`Disallow` is part of the [original robots.txt standard](https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) that is understood by every bot that obeys robots.txt.

`Allow` is extension syntax introduced by Google and understood by a few bots only.  It was added to be able to disallow everything but then re-allow a few things.  It would be most appropriate to use it like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /public
```

In that case, most bots wouldn't be able to crawl the site at all, but the few bots that understand `Allow:` would be able to crawl the public directory.

When `Disallow:` and `Allow:` directives conflict (as in the above example), the longer one that applies to a given URL takes precedence. Eg `/public/foo` would use the `Allow: /public` rule because both rules could apply but that rule is longer.  `/private/foo` would use the `Disallow: /` rule because only it matches. The order of rules makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The first one tells all user-agents such as web-crawlers or google index bots that they are allowed to explore all the website since `/` is the root path of the website, for example, `http://example.org` would be `/`, and `https://example.org/admin` would be `/admin` in your robots.txt

The `Disallow` directive does exactly the opposite, it tells the user-agents to stay out of said paths.

`Allow` and `Disallow` can be used in different ways, such as a whitelist or a blacklist.

And because of that, the following

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

is the same as

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

The easiest way of understanding this is by thinking that `Allow` and `Disallow` are like "lists" of paths, but just one type of directive ( `Allow`, or `Disallow` ) should be used.

For example, let's blacklist our robots.txt using the `Disallow` directive, only denying the bing indexer to index our website.

```
User-agent: Bingbot
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

In short.

If disallow is empty, then everything is allowed.

And if you allow everything, then nothing is disallowed.